# VariableDeclaratorId expected on @SuppressWarnings

Tags: java

As `@SuppressWarnings annotation` applies to

```
TYPE,FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,CONSTRUCTOR,LOCAL_VARIABLE
```

I have tried to do

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
differenceList = (List<Integer>) CollectionUtils.subtract(newId,oldId);
```

where `differenceList` is a list of Integers declared beforehand.
But in eclipse , i got the following error-

```
Syntax error on token "differenceList", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
     this token
```

but if i do

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer> someList = (List<Integer>) CollectionUtils.subtract(newId, oldId);
```

I get no error.

Why is that in the first case it asks for `VariableDeclaratorId`  and how can i make it work? I dont want to use @SuppressWarnings before the method as the doc says, use it at the lowest possible level in order to avoid hiding the warning in situations where it should not be suppressed.  Is there any work around?

(Java 6)

Comment: Annotations in Java 7 (I'm not sure about java 8) can just be used on declarations of everything, not everywhere else.

Comment: No, there's no workaround. Try annotating the declaration.

Comment: Even if I annotate the declaration, and repeatedly call the same method, it issues warning from the second time onwards. So how do i suppress them?

Answer (score 2):

Java annotations can only annotate declarations .

Comment: if that is the case is there any work around if i want to use it this way